# Regex exclude a specific pattern

Tags: python, regex

I am writing a regex to preprocess some tweets. Many a times I come across spellings like `hiiiii` or `looove` etc. I am trying to clean them to `hi` or `love` to clean usage of multiple consecutive characters. My code is as follows:

```
 w = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]|(.)(?=\1)', '', w)
```

This does most of the job but it also cleans words like `book` to `bok` or `deep` to `dep`. I want to exclude `oo` and `ee` from this pattern. Tried doing this:

```
w = re.sub(r'(?!oo)[^\w\s]|(.)(?=\1)', '', "book")
```

But this didn't work. Please help.

Comment: Honestly you should be checking against a dictionary. You could even use it to build a regex, but you’re going to have bad results until a dictionary is involved.

Comment: There are *literally* hundreds of words with repeating letters that aren't o or e. Even within your examples and with your solution, *loove* will be allowed because you'll be allowing oo.

Comment: @zzxyz This step is before checking with a dictionary. I am using levenshtein's distance to check against dictionary but at times the distance is too big due to such patterns. Thats why this preprocess

Comment: Check the dictionary first, before “cleaning” a word, IMO. Then check it again later, if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this regex?

```
[^\w\s]|(.)(?=\1(?<![^o]oo|[^e]ee))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/P074q8/9)